# How to make lazy Set?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iterator, hashset, iterable

```js
new Set(getObjects())
```

`getObjects` returns an iterable object. Every iteration a new object is created. But `Set` gets and adds all of new objects immediately.

How to make it so only when a new object is needed, a new object is gotten and added?

I tried `Proxy` but no handler fires when calling a function with `receiver` as `this`.

```js
const getEntitySet = (nativeEntityCollection) => {
  const cache = new Set;

  let src = {
    [Symbol.iterator]: ((itr) => {
      return () => itr;
    })(nativeEntityCollection[Symbol.iterator]()),
    ref: nativeEntityCollection
  };

  let addAll = () => {
    for (const entity of src) {
      cache.add(entity)
    }
    done()
  };

  let generate = function*() {
    yield* cache;
    for (const entity of src) {
      cache.add(entity);
      yield entity;
    }
    done()
  };

  const done = () => {
    src = null;
    addAll = null;
    generate = Reflect.get(cache, Symbol.iterator).bind(cache)
  };

  const generateRef = () => generate();
  return new Proxy(cache, {
    get(set, prop) {
      if (prop === Symbol.iterator) {
        return generateRef;
      }
      addAll?.();
      return Reflect.get(cache, prop);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: You can't use a Set for that - it has no ability to handle a collection created on demand.  Just use a generator.

Comment: What do you mean by "*when a new object is needed*"? A set needs to be able to lookup all values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The receiver issue you mention can be reproduced when using other methods on the proxy object than `Symbol.iterator`, like `has`.

This can be fixed by using `bind` (as you already did elsewhere):

```
return Reflect.get(cache, prop).bind(cache);
```

This will fix that issue.

#### Other remarks

An *access* to a method will trigger `addAll`, which is a pity, as it is not certain that this access will really need that to happen. For instance, if we just did `const f = myproxy.has`, then there is actually no need to greedily consume the iterable.

With the proxy pattern you would have to return a replacing function for such method access, and only have `addAll` called within that returned function. I would suggest to use an inheritance pattern instead of the proxy pattern. This seems more suitable for implementing the desired behaviour.

In the case of the `has` method, we could even consider to *partially* consume the iterable up to the point that the target element is found, as any further consumption of that iterable could never change the outcome of this method call.

### Implementation

Here is an alternative "subclassing" implementation you could consider:

```js
class LazySet extends Set {
    #iterator
    
    constructor(iterable) {
        super();
        this.#iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
        this.#iterator.return = () => ({}); // Disable undesired return behaviour
    }
    * values() {
        yield* super.values();
        if (!this.#iterator) return;
        let size = super.size;
        for (const value of this.#iterator) {
            super.add(value); // lazy
            if (size === super.size) continue; // duplicate
            yield value;
            size++;
        }
        this.#iterator = null; // release reference
    }
    * entries() {
        for (const value of this.values()) yield [value, value];
    }
    * keys() {
        yield* this.values();
    }
    * [Symbol.iterator]() {
        yield* this.values();
    }
    forEach(cb, thisArg) {
        for (const value of this.values()) {
            cb.call(thisArg, value, this);
        }
    }
    has(needle) {
        if (super.has(needle)) return true;
        if (!this.#iterator) return false;
        for (const value of this.#iterator) {
            super.add(value); // lazy
            if (value === needle) return true;
        }
        this.#iterator = null;
        return false;
    }
    delete(needle) {
        for (const _ of this.values()) {}; // consume iterator
        return super.delete(needle);
    }
    get size() {
        for (const _ of this.values()) {}; // consume iterator
        return super.size;
    } 
}

// Demo
function* generator() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        console.log(`  (about to yield ${i})`);
        yield i;
    }
}

let set = new LazySet(generator());
console.log("Does set have 3?:");
console.log(set.has(3));
console.log("-----------------");
console.log("first 5 values in set:");
let i = 0;
for (const value of set) {
    console.log(value);
    if (++i === 5) break;
}
console.log("-----------------");
console.log("All values in set:");
console.log(...set);
console.log("size:", set.size);
```

Comment: Two nits: The `iterable` parameter/field better should be named `iterator` (especially since you overwrite its `return` method), and `has` should use `Object.is` instead of `===`. Also you might want to release the reference to the iterator once you actually consumed it completely.

Comment: Thanks Bergi. Addressed those points. I took the @@iterator from the iterable. Added `size` getter which was missing.

Comment: What about `func.apply()` and `func.call()`?

Comment: What about it ? What do you want to say about `apply` and `call`?

Comment: I would use `#set = new Set();` instead of `extends Set` because `Set.prototype.has.call(lazy)` doesn't call subclass's `has`.

Comment: Of course it doesn't call the subclass's `has` when you explicitly bypass it. Why is that a problem? This is how it is intended to work in JS. For comparison: `Date` subclasses `Object`, and so `new Date().valueOf()` does not do the same thing as `Object.prototype.valueOf.call(new Date())`.

Comment: That's weird but okay. Why doesn't `ProxyHandler` have a handler for `call`?

Comment: As to your other question: There is a proxy handler for function calls, but then the said function must be object of the proxy. A function call is an action on the function object, and so if you want to trap that, you must proxy the function object itself. I don't see that as a good solution for the lazy set you want to implement.